# My foreach is only applying to the first instance

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a wordpress site where my index page will display the post title, thumbnail, and list all available post categories. Each instance of a post will also display all available post categories. For each category the post has, the category name should be highlighted with a light blue background color. Currently the background color feature is working for only the first post and not the other three.

My code below is intended to push each of the post's categories into an array and search the array for the given category (the code below searches for just one of the categories for brevity's sake here). If the category is found, a jQuery script should execute highlighting the category name but as I say above, it's only functioning for the first post.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<section class="blog-index">
<?php 
$args = array('showposts' => 3);
$recent = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $recent->have_posts() ): 
    echo '<div class="blog-index-list">';

while ( $recent->have_posts()) :
    $recent->the_post(); 
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $cats = array();                                            
    foreach($categories as $category) {                             
        $cats[] = $category->name;
    }
    if(in_array("Academia", $cats)) {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              jQuery('#A').addClass('active');
              jQuery('#A').css({'background-color': #009edb', 'color': '#ffffff'});
              </script>";
    }

    echo '<article> 
              <h2><hr class="orange-line above-left">   <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">
              <span class="dark-blue">' .get_field('dark_blue_hero'). '</span><br/>
              <span class="light-blue">' .get_field('light_blue_hero') . '</span></a>
              </h2>
          <ul class="all-categories">
                  <li id="G">G</li>
                  <li id="A">A</li>
                  <li id="I">I</li>
                  <li id="N">N</li>
          </ul>
          <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'' .
          '<div class="blog-index-button et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_module et_pb_button_alignment_center">
             <a class="et_pb_button  et_pb_button_3 et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">READ POST</a>
           </div>                   
          </article>';
endwhile; 
echo '</div>';
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: Because you only apply the javascript to the li with `id=A`, even if the other categories are in the `$cats` array they won't be highlighted because of your javascript code.

Comment: The code searches for just one of the categories for brevity's sake here. Two of my posts are categorized as 'Academia' but only the first post has it highlighted. That's the problem.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't repeat `id="A"` in every article. Use a class if you need to repeat it.

Comment: Your img tag is broken, it never ends.

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique (as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910379/my-foreach-is-only-applying-to-the-first-instance#comment72920412_42910623) said) but it is still possible to have multiple elements with the same ID. And it is possible to select them with jQuery. That is why I'll also explain how to do it with classes.

When you use the jQuery ID selector ([`jQuery("#id")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)) it selects the first element with the given ID `id`.

To select all elements with ID `id` you can select them by their attribute(s):

```
jQuery("li[id=id]")
```

Since IDs should be unique it is better to use classes. Using the jQuery class selector [`jQuery(".class")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) you can select all the elements with the class `class`. You should change your li elements to have classes instead of IDs and select those classes with jQuery.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct, but if the someone decides to use duplicate IDs this will work.

Comment: Maybe, but it would be better to show them how to do it correctly with classes.

Comment: @TomUdding now my jQuery looks like this:

     `if(in_array("Academia", $cats)) {
              
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          jQuery('li[id=A]').addClass('active');
          jQuery('li[id=A]').css({'background-color': '#009edb', 'color': '#ffffff'});
          </script>";
       }`

Still not working, is that what you meant?

Comment: You should use classes for your li elements as @Barmar pointed out, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @TomUdding I've tried this with classes but it didn't work either. Here is the code with Id's but I'm still having the same problem.
    
                          ` foreach($categories as $category) {              
             $cats[] = $category->name;
         }
             if(in_array("Academia", $cats)) {
              
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          jQuery('li[id=A]').addClass('active');
          jQuery('li[id=A]').css({'background-color': '#009edb', 'color': '#ffffff'});
          </script>";
       }`

Comment: What do you mean with "It does not work!"??? Yes, the code will select everything, even tags that shouldn't be marked. Use inline css instead.

Comment: I mean that by changing the selector to be jQuery ('li[id=A]') did not change anything about the code's functionality. It still only applies styling to the first element with that ID that it finds.

Comment: @AFarkas I would bet that the problem is not related to your jQuery, but rather to your interspersal of jQuery and PHP.  It may be that the html with the "A" id isn't even on the page when the jQuery gets run.  My suggestion would be to put all of this jQuery code into a js file that you include on the bottom of the page and put then apply it conditionally.

Comment: thank you @vlasits I will give this a whirl!